# cakephp compare array with database fields

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I'm developing an app in cakePHP. I'm supposed to take an array $data, which contains username and password (non-hashed), and compare it to all rows in table Customers where if it matches any row I'll send a message back saying user found. This is the code I've written:

```
$data = $this->request->input('json_decode');
$data = $this->Customer->findByUsernameAndPassword('data.firstname','data.lastname');

if ($data) { ...message...}
```

Now I know that data is being set correctly, I know the problem is with the comparing parameters 'data.firstname' etc. What should be the correct syntax?

Comment: Should you not be passing the arguments to findByUsernameAndPassword as variables? You are passing two strings "data.firstname" and "data.lastname" in this example.

Comment: Yes, ideally I would, but I'm receiving JSON data into $data array like this:
stdClass Object
(
    [username] => john
    [password] => merriweather
)
I don't know how to compare this to fields in database...what would be the correct command? thanks so much for replying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$data = $this->Customer->findByUsernameAndPassword($data['username'],$data['password']);
```